# Java Exception

Tags: java

Добрый День. Есть пример :

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        g();
    }
    public static void g() throws Error {
    }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему этот код компилируется ? Читаю Хорстманна и вижу : "Компилятор строго следит за спецификаторами throws. Вызывая метод, генерирующий контролируемое исключение, нужно либо самому обработать его, либо делегировать обработку другому методу". Получается, что все неконтролируемые исключения из классов Error И RuntimeException обрабатывать не обязательно ? И еще у нас есть метод main который бросает контролируемое исключение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

разве его не нужно где то обработать. Читаю и не пойму, как правильно трактовать смысл. Расскажите пожалуйста, как нужно поступать в данном примере и вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Скажите пожалуйста, почему этот код компилируется ?

Почему он не должен?

JLS §11.2:

> The unchecked exception classes are exempted from compile-time
> checking
>
> Of the unchecked exception classes, error classes are exempted because they can occur at
> many points in the program and recovery from them is difficult or impossible.

.

> Получается, что все неконтролируемые исключения из классов Error И RuntimeException обрабатывать не обязательно ?

Поэтому они называются "неконтролируемыми" (unchecked).

> разве его не нужно где то обработать.

Исключения проброшенные вверх методом `main` вам обработает виртуальная машина. Ну как обработает... Выведет stacktrace в stderr и завершит выполнение.

Comment: вот как раз я и хотел узнать, получается что бросая исключения в методе main программа просто завершит выполнение ? где можно прочитать про этот нюанс ?

Comment: Вот тут: JLS §11.3 [Run-Time Handling of an Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3)

> If no catch clause that can handle an exception can be found, then the current thread (the thread that encountered the exception) is terminated.

Comment: Скажите, если мы выбросили исключение throws Error и не обработали, то исключение должно обрабатываться в вызывающем его методе, то есть main. Но ведь получается, что исключения Error и Exception это разные исключения из разных классов. Как метод g() с исключением Error может обрабатываться методом main с исключением Exception ?

Comment: Вы просто отправляете меня читать JLS, что для меня это сейчас очень трудно. Я на русском пока не очень понимаю, и поэтому иностранный источник не использую. Для вас это очевидные вещи, а для меня это пока глухой лес и видя такой не очевидный для меня пример стараюсь понять все тонкости.

Comment: Ок, пнятненько. В общем, JLS говорит нам, что забивает на проверки unchecked-исключений при компиляции. То есть, то, что вы указали в сигнатуре метода `throws Error`, равносильно отсутствию соответствующей инструкции.

---

Посмотрите на это так: 

Метод `g()` может бросить `Error`. Ок, протолкнем его в метод `main`. Т.е. в методе `main` произойдет исключение `Error`. Это проверяемое исключение? Нет. Ну, значит компилятору и беспокоиться нечего. Ведь `Error` у вас и так может в любой момент случиться.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо вам большое.